# When restrained or unconscious, do you lose your Dexterity bonus to AC?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor-class, unconscious

If a character is restrained or unconscious/sleeping, do they lose any bonus from dexterity for armor class and dexterity saves?

Comment: Related (maybe duplicate): [Does an unconscious creature still use its dexterity to avoid attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101919/does-an-unconscious-creature-still-use-its-dexterity-to-avoid-attacks)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

AC calculations do not change, however you do automatically fail strength and dex saves (PHB 292).

AC calculations do not change based on your state of consciousness or other conditions. You will grant advantage on attacks, but your armor calculations don't change.

This is likely for ease of use rather than any kind of mechanical simulation.

Generally, AC calculations are something you do once when you level up (generally it only changes if you get an ability increase related to ac or take a feat so that's pretty obvious) or get new gear and do not change (though as a commenter points out you *may* need to keep a record of your unarmored ac if your DM plans to gank you in your sleep). Unless something *specifically* grants a bonus/penalty, AC is going to be constant.

With the automatic *failure* of dex/str saves, you don't have to worry about any bonuses to those saves, you simply fail them.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that as of the [2018 PHB errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf), [grapple](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) and [shove](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature) attempts automatically succeed against incapacitated creatures.